# Instagram OAuth user data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, instagram

I have an app for client side Instagram login. So far, user can successfully login into Instagram and recieve access token. The problem is that I want to make a request, and get the Instagram user data, but don't know how. I also want to know how to clear user's access token to logout.

My code:

```
angular.module('instagramApp.services', []).factory('instagramService', function($q) {

   var authorizationResult = false;

   return {
      initialize: function() {

        authorizationResult = OAuth.create('instagram');
      },

      isReady: function() {
        return (authorizationResult);
      },
      connectInstagram: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        OAuth.redirect('instagram', 'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='CLIENT_ID'&redirect_uri=http://localhost/insta-login&response_type=token');
        return deferred.promise;
    }
  }

});
```